# Do `%f, %F, %u, %U` belong to bash?

Tags: bash, .desktop

[image]

I don't find `%f, %F, %u, %U` in bash manual.

In `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop`, I also see similar usage:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=gedit
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=gedit %U
```

Do `%f, %F, %u, %U` belong to bash?

If not, what uses them?

Comment: They are based on the [freedesktop Desktop Entry Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html)

Answer (score 5):

No, they are provided by the software that created the window.

Comment: Thanks. What, if not bash, uses them?

Comment: The software that created the window.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Recognized Desktop Entry Keys](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) of [FreeDesktop](https://www.freedesktop.org).

Specifically have a look at the [`Exec` Key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html).
In your case `$U` means it should handle the input which comes after the call to the program as URL Address.

Comment: Remark - See https://askubuntu.com/a/30214/712598.